# Challenges in Packaging and Distributing a ROS 2 Application with C++ and Python Components

Tags: ros2, sensors, package, build, windows

**Hi!**

I am working on a project involving a ROS 2 application that integrates both C++ and Python components. The application is designed to visualize data from automotive radars and is developed using ROS 2 binary packages. Currently, I am facing challenges in packaging and distributing this application for internal use.

**Current Setup:**

- The application consists of two separate parts communicating through ROS 2 topics.
- It's built using the colcon build tool.
- A batch script is used to launch the application, which includes sourcing the ROS 2 setup script and the workspace's local setup scripts.

**Issues:**

**Packaging Complexity:** I am struggling to create a unified package that can easily be installed and executed by end-users, especially considering the mixed use of C++ and Python.
**Distribution Method:** I am contemplating whether to use tools like Chocolatey for distribution on Windows, but I am unsure of its effectiveness, especially for an application that relies heavily on ROS 2 and has specific environment setup requirements.

**Questions:**

What are the best practices for packaging a mixed C++/Python ROS 2 application for easy installation?
Can Chocolatey be effectively used for distributing such an application on Windows, and how would it handle ROS 2 dependencies and environment setup?
Are there any recommended tools or strategies specifically for ROS 2 applications that can simplify the distribution process across different operating systems?

***Any insights, suggestions, or experiences shared would be incredibly helpful.***

**Thank you!**